# Bootstrap columns not appearing inline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and CSS in general. I have some html which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"><span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><span id="cool-title">My Site</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-bar">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search col-md-1"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="main">
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want all of those `col-` divs to be inlined, but they are all showing up on their own rows:

[image: Not inlined]

What's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `/css/bootstrap-theme.css`. Use `/css/bootstrap.css` or `/css/bootstrap.min.css` instead. bootstrap-theme.css doesn't have "col- " properties.

Also, instead of using just one `class="col-md-1"` (for medium sized viewport/screen) you might want to use something like `class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"` that makes your columns responsive to different screens. ('xs' for extra small screen, 'lg' for large screen etc. Play around with these numbers. Bootstrap uses a 12 columns grid layout, so use factors of 12 as the numbers.)

Comment: wow thank you! who would have thunk that the one thing for which bootstrap is probably most famous for "grids" is not included in the min version.. if anything that's the only thing that should be included in it

Answer (score 1):

If you are viewing it with small screen width then use following way:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1"><span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"><span id="cool-title">My Site</span></div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-bar">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
      <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search col-md-1"> button</i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Experiment with changing **col-md-#**(column number) or others to achieve your desired result.

**Liveweave** : http://liveweave.com/9MGL33

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your screen resolution is too small. If you don't want to add responsive behaviour, you should start with col-xs-*, so the columns will always be horizontal (or inline).
Remember that bootstrap uses 12 columns by default, so maybe col-xs-1 will be a little to small.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1"><span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"><span id="cool-title">My Site</span></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-bar">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search col-md-1"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4 for extra small screens do not declare "col-xs-#" it's just "col-#". Took 2 hours of banging my head against the wall to figure it out.

So instead of

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">L</div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">M</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">R</div>
  </div>
```

It should be

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">L</div>
    <div class="col-10">M</div>
    <div class="col-1">R</div>
  </div>
```