# Post in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've stuck in dev WP theme, please help me.
The problem is when  I wrote code for displaying post in *front-page.php*, it display me the_title() and the_content() from page, not from post.
There is code:

```
   <?php if(have_posts()): ?>
   <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   <h2 class="blog-post-title"><?php the_title( );  ?> </h2>
   <?php the_content(); ?>
   <?php endwhile; else: ?>
   <p><?php __('No post found') ?></p>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

It displays me post only if I go to post location e.g. localhost/2017/10/16/first-post/.

There is picture how it correctly shows but on another location.
http://prntscr.com/gy922y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are displaying in a custom page, You'll need to declare and specify `post_type` as `post`

Here is a working example:

```
        <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );

    $post_query = new WP_Query($args);
if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
  while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
    $post_query->the_post();
    ?>
<h2 class="blog-post-title"><?php the_title( );  ?> </h2>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank your for answer, now I have problem with displaying it inline, it's already in bootstrap grid system with class="row", but it ain't displaying inline, I tried with inline css style="display:inline;", but nothing.

Comment: I have no clue what's your css code, but have you tried `display: inline-block;` You need to share your css code block if that didn't help.

Comment: There is ss of code, even with inline-block it doesn't work http://prntscr.com/gy9hj1, there is ss of front-end: http://prntscr.com/gy9hzl.

Comment: I meant your main css theme file. Look for `col-md-4` and replace `display: block;` with `display: inline-block;` OR `display: inline;`

Comment: Those are Bootstrap classes, predefined, in basic html code works properly,  but when I put this php loop, they don't for some reasons.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319906/bootstrap-columns-not-appearing-inline

Comment: There is html code which works to me, Anyways thank you for help I will try to fix it by myself.